# How to add static(html, css, js, etc) files in pyinstaller to create standalone exe file?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qwebengineview

I'm using  `QtWebEngineWidgets`, `QtWebChannel` to create PyQt5 application, which uses HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

It's working fine, when we run in general way i.e., `python main.py`

Importing HTML as below,

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
```

Importing CSS, JavaScript files as below,

```
# in index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_custom.js"></script>
```

Now, I'm trying to create a standalone `.exe` file using `pyinstaller`.

I have tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/11844406) with no success.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

I need to manually add static files at generated `.exe` file to work as expected. Which I want to include it in `.exe` file itself. How to get this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your question you can presume that the structure of your project is as follows:

```
├── index.html
├── jquery.js
├── main.py
├── my_custom.js
└── styles.css
```

For your case there are 2 options:

1. using [`--add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)

   ```py
   import os
   import sys

   from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


   def resource_path(relative_path):
       """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
       try:
           # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
           base_path = sys._MEIPASS
       except Exception:
           base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

       return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys

       app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
       view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

       filename = resource_path("index.html")
       url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

       view.load(url)
       view.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

   If you want to add external resources to the executable then you must use the "--add-data" option:

   ```
   pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data="index.html:." --add-data="jquery.js:." --add-data="my_custom.js:." --add-data="styles.css:." main.py
   ```

   For windows change ":" with ";".
2. using [`.qrc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

   With this method you will convert the files (.html, .css, .js, etc) into .py code using pyrcc5 for this you must follow the following steps:

   2.1. Create a file called resource.qrc with the following content in the project folder:

   ```
   <RCC>
       <qresource prefix="/">
           <file>index.html</file>
           <file>jquery.js</file>
           <file>my_custom.js</file>
           <file>styles.css</file>
       </qresource>
   </RCC>
   ```

   2.2 Convert it to .py using pyrcc5:

   ```
   pyrcc5 resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py
   ```

   2.3 Import the resource_rc.py file and use the url with schema "qrc" in the main.py file:

   ```py
   import os
   import sys

   from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

   import resource_rc


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys

       app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
       view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

       url = QtCore.QUrl("qrc:/index.html")

       view.load(url)
       view.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

   2.4 Compile the project using your initial command

   ```
   pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
   ```

Comment: Thanks for helping. One small doubt,Using 2nd method: In HTML, do I need to import files as `<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///jquery.js"></script>`? or is there any other way?

Comment: Using first method, I got error `pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'index.html:.'`

Comment: @Pythoncoder try execute: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data="index.html;." --add-data="jquery.js;." --add-data="my_custom.js;." --add-data="styles.css;." main.py`

Comment: Yes, it is working with `;`. Thanks. What is the reason?

Comment: @Pythoncoder see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3968#issuecomment-564707533